# Pagination in DynamoDB when using QuerySpec.withMaxPageSize()

Tags: java, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use QuerySpec.withMaxPageSize(int limit) to implement pagination. I use it like this:

```
QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec()
        .withKeyConditionExpression("id = :v_id")
        .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
            .withString(":v_id", "1234"))
        .withScanIndexForward(false)
        .withMaxPageSize(Integer.parseInt(5));
ItemCollection<QueryOutcome>items = table.query(querySpec);
int startPage = 0;
for (Page<Item, QueryOutcome> page : items.pages()) {
    System.out.println("Page: " + ++startPage);

    Iterator<Item> iterator = page.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

Then the results is correct: every page has 5 items.

BUT when I use the QuerySpec like this:

```
QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec()
    .withKeyConditionExpression("id = :v_id")
    .withFilterExpression("eventType = :v_eventType")
    .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
         .withString(":v_id", "1234")
         .withString(":v_eventType", "event"))
    .withScanIndexForward(false)
    .withMaxPageSize(Integer.parseInt(5));
```

THEN the results is totally wrong:

```
Page: 1
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489480336243, eventType=starRating} }
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489476430129, eventType=starRating, }
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489460649642, eventType=starRating, }
Page: 2
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489137400014, eventType=starRating} }
Page: 3
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489137294383, eventType=starRating} }
Page: 4
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489137046331, eventType=starRating} }
Page: 5
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489137030983, eventType=starRating} }
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489137022138, eventType=starRating} }
Page: 6
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489136930427, eventType=starRating} }
Page: 7
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489136782467, eventType=starRating} }
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489136765162, eventType=starRating} }
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489136669765, eventType=starRating} }
Page: 8
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489136478857, eventType=starRating} }
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489136453453, eventType=starRating} }
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489136435202, eventType=starRating} }
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489136384098, eventType=starRating} }
Page: 9
{ Item: {id=1234, timestamp=1489136253163, eventType=starRating} }
```

Every page has different items. It seems like when I add the filter expression, there will be this problem. But I don't know why. Does anybody knows about this?

Comment: The results above has an error: the value of 'eventType' should be 'event'. I just make an example of my problem

Comment: I do not see any page having more than 5 items

Comment: Yeah, I have known the answer. Because I use FilterExpression. So the results will be divided into pages first, and then FILTER the results in every page based on the FilterExpression. Thanks @efekctive! Do you know how to implement the pagination if I use the second `querySpec` above?

Comment: The explanation given by @xtx seems reasonable. If I can think of anything else I will post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#ScanQueryLimit) that gives explanation why you are getting different number of rows per page:

> In a response, DynamoDB returns all the matching results within the
>   scope of the Limit value. For example, if you issue a Query or a Scan
>   request with a Limit value of 6 and without a filter expression,
>   DynamoDB returns the first six items in the table that match the
>   specified key conditions in the request (or just the first six items
>   in the case of a Scan with no filter). If you also supply a
>   FilterExpression value, DynamoDB will return the items in the first
>   six that also match the filter requirements (the number of results
>   returned will be less than or equal to 6).

So basically when you use FilterExpression along with Limit in Query, DynamoDB reads up to `Limit` records from table and then filters out those that do not match your `FilterExpression`.

---

**UPD:** In order to get an exact number of records per each page, you would have to use a bit more complex approach. After you get the first query result, if the subset returned contains less than `Limit` items, 
save records into a buffer and continue reading until the total number of items becomes >= Limit. If the number of records in your buffer exceeds Limit, throw away exceeding records. 
That's how you get the first page with exact size of `Limit` items (5 in your case).

To get the second page, you could run a new query providing KeyConditionExpression like 
`id = :v_id and #timestamp < :timestamp`, and use timestamp value of the last record of the previous page for `:timestamp`. Again, you would have to read multiple times until the total number of items in buffer becomes >= your preferred page size. Use the same approach to get all subsequent pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot@xtx. You have perfectly solve my problem. In addition, if I want to use FilterExpression, How can I implement pagination?

Comment: Hi @xtx, I think this solution is a little complex, When I have a large number of items, this will be very slow. I want to use the `LastEvaluatedKey`, but seems like it is not support for `QuerySpec` or `ScanSpec` ...

Comment: Both QuerySpec and ScanSpec support withExclusiveStartKey, which is where you pass LastEvaluatedKey value from the previous result.

Comment: No matter whether you use `withExclusiveStartKey`, or KeyConditionExpression with additional timestamp condition to start retrieving the next page's data, in order to get the same number of rows per each page, you would need to make multiple requests per page (when using FilterExpression). So both approaches could be slow.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of withExclusiveStartKey to implement pagination (with QuerySpec / ScanSpec) @xtx? no matter whether use FilterExpression.

Comment: Here is an example of how you can add ExclusiveStartKey to your QuerySpec / ScanSpec: `.withExclusiveStartKey("id", 1234, "timestamp", 1489137046331)`.  By the way items.pages() iterator also uses LastEvaluatedKey internally when requesting a next page. Anyway, you got the idea: if you want all pages to have the same size, you'll need to make multiple queries per page.